# How to put breakpoint at random instruction

Tags: python, random, gdb, breakpoints, cpu-registers

I have to do this, repeatedly many times:

1. Start execution of program
2. **Stop at random point during execution**
3. Modify value in register
4. Continue execution

Until now, I've been using **GDB** extended with **Python** and the only struggle is to stop randomly during execution.

Already tried approaches:

- Retrieve binary file sections and pick random address among executable instructions.
  ----> **Problem**: too low probability of hitting set breakpoints, takes too long to obtain valuable results.
- Break at `_start` and do `stepi {rand_num}` to skip `{rand_num}` instructions, then alter register.
  ----> **Problem**: infeasible, programs under test contain too many instructions, too long test execution time.
- Send signal `SIGINT` to the inferior process, after waiting a random amount of time. ----> **Problem**: programs under test execute in less than 30ms, problems with temporization.

How would you do? Which tools would you use?

Thank you in advance! :)

Comment: Would `step {rand_num}` followed by `stepi {another_rand_num}` be efficient enough?

Comment: More info needed: what platform? What processor? The intel processor trace (inel-pt) can help a lot if you can use it.

Comment: @EmployedRussian I'm using a custom kernel Ubuntu 18.04 on ARM Cortex A9

Comment: There's also [c - How to make GDB stepi faster? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67088007/how-to-make-gdb-stepi-faster)