# How to make GDB stepi faster?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

I am using GDB to log the executed assembly instruction.

Here is the GDB script I made:

**log.gdb**

```
set confirm off
tbreak start_trigger
r
set logging overwrite on
set logging on
set height 0
set style enabled off
while (1) 
    x/i $pc
    stepi
end
quit
```

And I ran gdb using

```
$ gdb results-mte/aha-compress.elf -x script.gdb -batch
```

This works well and writes the `gdb.txt` but it is ***really slow***. Is there any way to make it faster?

Comment: Sure this is slow. You are tracing each single instruction, what do you expect? -- This looks to me like an [X-Y-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you want to achieve? There might be another solution.

Comment: I made a custom instruction on QEMU and I need to get the list of assembly instructions executed for the BEEBS benchmark binary on RISCV. I'm running this GDB inside a Fedora RiscV on QEMU. I tried to use gdb from host to qemu, it is faster but for some binary, it failed to access memory even if I already added 'nokaslr' on kernel param.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to make it faster?

Yes: don't do that.

*Think* about how single-stepping works. On a processor which supports single-step in hardware, GDB has to

- enable single-stepping
- resume inferior
- wait for OS to deliver `SIGCHLD`
- query inferior for current registers (`$pc` mostly) via `ptrace`
- decode and print current instruction

... repeat for each instruction. This is expected to be about 1000-10000 times slower than native execution.

Usual solutions are to use some tracing mechanism. E.g. using `intel_pt` trace would make this only slightly slower than full native speed.

> I'm running this GDB inside a Fedora RiscV on QEMU.

Now you are emulating the GDB itself, adding another factor of 10 or more slowdown.

What you *probably* want to do is ask QEMU to record the instructions it executes.

Typing "qemu trace instructions" into Google produces [this post](https://rwmj.wordpress.com/2016/03/17/tracing-qemu-guest-execution/) (among others).